# OpenGL Computing Normals and TBN Matrix from Depth Buffer (SSAO implementation)

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, depth-buffer, ssao

I'm implementing SSAO in OpenGL, following this tutorial: [Jhon Chapman SSAO](http://john-chapman-graphics.blogspot.ca/2013/01/ssao-tutorial.html)

Basically the technique described uses an Hemispheric kernel which is oriented along the fragment's normal. The view space z position of the sample is then compared to its screen space depth buffer value. 
If the value in the depth buffer is higher, it means the sample ended up in a geometry so this fragment should be occluded.

The goal of this technique is to get rid of the classic implementation artifact where objects flat faces are greyed out.

I've have the same implementation with 2 small differencies

- I'm not using a Noise texture to rotate my kernel, so I have banding artifacts, that's fine for now
- I don't have access to a buffer with Per-pixel normals, so I have to compute my normal and TBN matrix only using the depth buffer.

The algorithm seems to be working fine, I can see the fragments being occluded, BUT I still have my faces greyed out...
IMO it's coming from the way I'm calculating my TBN matrix. The normals look OK but something must be wrong as my kernel doesn't seem to be properly aligned causing samples to end up in the faces.

Screenshots are with a Kernel of 8 samples and a radius of .1. the first is only the result of SSAO pass and the second one is the debug render of the generated normals.

**Here is the code for the function that computes the Normal and TBN Matrix**

```
    mat3 computeTBNMatrixFromDepth(in sampler2D depthTex, in vec2 uv)
    {
        // Compute the normal and TBN matrix
        float ld = -getLinearDepth(depthTex, uv);
        vec3 x = vec3(uv.x, 0., ld);
        vec3 y = vec3(0., uv.y, ld);
        x = dFdx(x);
        y = dFdy(y);
        x = normalize(x);
        y = normalize(y);
        vec3 normal = normalize(cross(x, y));
        return mat3(x, y, normal);
    }
```

**And the SSAO shader**

```
#include "helper.glsl"

in vec2 vertTexcoord;
uniform sampler2D depthTex;

const int MAX_KERNEL_SIZE = 8;
uniform vec4 gKernel[MAX_KERNEL_SIZE];

// Kernel Radius in view space (meters)
const float KERNEL_RADIUS = .1; 

uniform mat4 cameraProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 cameraProjectionMatrixInverse;

out vec4 FragColor;


void main()
{   
    // Get the current depth of the current pixel from the depth buffer (stored in the red channel)
    float originDepth = texture(depthTex, vertTexcoord).r;

    // Debug linear depth. Depth buffer is in the range [1.0];
    float oLinearDepth = getLinearDepth(depthTex, vertTexcoord);

    // Compute the view space position of this point from its depth value
    vec4 viewport = vec4(0,0,1,1);    
    vec3 originPosition = getViewSpaceFromWindow(cameraProjectionMatrix, cameraProjectionMatrixInverse, viewport, vertTexcoord, originDepth);

    mat3 lookAt = computeTBNMatrixFromDepth(depthTex, vertTexcoord);
    vec3 normal = lookAt[2];

    float occlusion = 0.;

    for (int i=0; i<MAX_KERNEL_SIZE; i++) 
    {
        // We align the Kernel Hemisphere on the fragment normal by multiplying all samples by the TBN        
        vec3 samplePosition = lookAt * gKernel[i].xyz;

        // We want the sample position in View Space and we scale it with the kernel radius
        samplePosition = originPosition + samplePosition * KERNEL_RADIUS;

        // Now we need to get sample position in screen space
        vec4 sampleOffset = vec4(samplePosition.xyz, 1.0);
        sampleOffset = cameraProjectionMatrix * sampleOffset;
        sampleOffset.xyz /= sampleOffset.w;

        // Now to get the depth buffer value at the projected sample position
        sampleOffset.xyz = sampleOffset.xyz * 0.5 + 0.5;

        // Now can get the linear depth of the sample
        float sampleOffsetLinearDepth = -getLinearDepth(depthTex, sampleOffset.xy);

        // Now we need to do a range check to make sure that object 
        // outside of the kernel radius are not taken into account
        float rangeCheck = abs(originPosition.z - sampleOffsetLinearDepth) < KERNEL_RADIUS ? 1.0 : 0.0;

        // If the fragment depth is in front so it's occluding
        occlusion += (sampleOffsetLinearDepth >= samplePosition.z ? 1.0 : 0.0) * rangeCheck;
    }  

    occlusion = 1.0 - (occlusion / MAX_KERNEL_SIZE);
    FragColor = vec4(vec3(occlusion), 1.0);
}
```

[image: Computed Normals from Depth buffer]
[image: SSAO Pass]

**Update 1**

This variation of the TBN calculation function gives the same results

```
mat3 computeTBNMatrixFromDepth(in sampler2D depthTex, in vec2 uv)
{
    // Compute the normal and TBN matrix
    float ld = -getLinearDepth(depthTex, uv);
    vec3 a = vec3(uv, ld);
    vec3 x = vec3(uv.x + dFdx(uv.x), uv.y, ld + dFdx(ld));
    vec3 y = vec3(uv.x, uv.y + dFdy(uv.y), ld + dFdy(ld));
    //x = dFdx(x);
    //y = dFdy(y);
    //x = normalize(x);
    //y = normalize(y);
    vec3 normal = normalize(cross(x - a, y - a));
    vec3 first_axis = cross(normal, vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    vec3 second_axis = cross(first_axis, normal);
    return mat3(normalize(first_axis), normalize(second_axis), normal);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is probably that you are mixing coordinate systems. You are using texture coordinates in combination with the linear depth. You can imagine two vertical surfaces facing slightly to the left of the screen. Both have the same angle from the vertical plane and should thus have the same normal right?

But let's then imagine that one of these surfaces are much further from the camera. Since fFdx/fFdy functions basically tell you the difference from the neighbor pixel, the surface far away from the camera will have greater linear depth difference over one pixel, than the surface close to the camera. But the uv.x / uv.y derivative will have the same value. That means that you will get different normals depending on the distance from the camera.

The solution is to calculate the view coordinate and use the derivative of that to calculate the normal.

```
vec3 viewFromDepth(in sampler2D depthTex, in vec2 uv, in vec3 view)
{
    float ld = -getLinearDepth(depthTex, uv);

    /// I assume ld is negative for fragments in front of the camera
    /// not sure how getLinearDepth is implemented

    vec3 z_scaled_view = (view / view.z) * ld;

    return z_scaled_view;
}

mat3 computeTBNMatrixFromDepth(in sampler2D depthTex, in vec2 uv, in vec3 view)
{
    vec3 view = viewFromDepth(depthTex, uv);

    vec3 view_normal = normalize(cross(dFdx(view), dFdy(view)));
    vec3 first_axis = cross(view_normal, vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    vec3 second_axis = cross(first_axis, view_normal);

    return mat3(view_normal, normalize(first_axis), normalize(second_axis));
}
```

Comment: I'm note sure I understand what you mean by saying that I'm sampling only one depth... Using the dFdx and dFdy on my vectors will actually compare two depth positions for the x and two depth positions for the y axis and return me the derivatives on those two axis. I've tried to modify my TBN function to reflect your comment, but ended up with the same result, see **Update 1**

Comment: Sorry. You are correct. I haven't really used dFdx/dFdy functions much. I didn't realize they worked like that. Anyway, I still think the problem is that your are not calculating it in view space. Please see my edit